# Exchange Server 2003 Shared Calendar

Tags: exchange-2003, calendar

I have created 2 users on exchange server 2003 and shared the calendar between them and i am able to see the shared calendar details when i click the calendar folder option.
I then tried creating a new calendar appointment  but when click on scheduling to see the schedule for other user i am getting the vertical lines for 'No information' avaliability.

Let me explain you the senerio i installed E2K3 on Win Server 2003 on a virtual machine in a specific domain then i installed E2k7 on Win Server 2008 64 bit machine i was able to send and receive mails from E2K7 but was unable to send and receive through E2k3 later found that drivers required for Networks are longer working on E2k3 machine, tried trouble shooting it but could not make it. we then installed E2k3 on another machine in domain and here we were able to send and receive mails but now shared calenders are not working, Schedule+Free Busy Folder is Empty without any subfolder in ESM.

Can some one please help me out in getting the shared calendar details

Thanks and Regards,
Haseena

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make sure Outlook is publishing free-busy information.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197712

Comment: Hi can you please suggest some good sites where i can find a deep data related to free-busy calender sharing in exchange.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but nothing worked out.